# React @react-awesome-query-builder throws "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'RCE')" error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I recently upgraded from react-awesome-query-builder 4.7.0 to @react-awesome-query-builder 6.4.2 and I am having a weird issue which I am unable to figgure out why. This is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'RCE')
    at Object.renderProvider (index.js:62:1)
    at QueryContainer._this.QueryWrapper (QueryContainer.js:62:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27381:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26422:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26390:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25806:1)
```

```
renderProvider: function renderProvider(props, _ref11) {
    var RCE = _ref11.RCE,
        MuiProvider = _ref11.W.MuiProvider;
    return RCE(MuiProvider, props);
},
```

Here is the place where it is thrown:

```
return (
    <>
        <Query {...config} value={tree} onChange={onChange} renderBuilder={renderBuilder} />
        {errors.map((error, index) => (
          <Alert key={`${index}-${error}`} color="error" children={error} />
        ))}
    </>
)
```

I tried to use custom BaseConfig, change renderBuilder. But I was expecting it to wrok as it was without having too much headache.

Send help pls

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. I forgot to add ctx field to the default config I am using. So I have a getConfig function that looks like this now:

```js
export default (targetGroup: TargetGroups, isReadOnly = false) => ({
  conjunctions,
  operators,
  widgets,
  types,
  settings: isReadOnly ? { ...settings, ...readOnly } : { ...settings },
  fields: getFields(targetGroup),
  ctx: initialConfig.ctx, // This ctx field was added
  funcs,
})
```